# Почему стейт обновляется только после второго нажатия?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда запускаю функцию на обновление стейта, то он обновляется только после второго нажатия?

```
const [isFormsValid, setIsFormsValid] = useState({})

const handleSelfValidation = (isFormValid: boolean, formIndex: number) => {
    console.log(isFormValid, formIndex, 'test')
    setIsFormsValid((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [formIndex]: isFormValid,
    }))
    console.log(isFormsValid) // показывает впервый раз пустой массив, хотя должен показать обновленный, ведь перед консоль логом функция (setIsFormsValid) которая меняет состояние
  };

//валидация происходит вот тут 
const handleValid = () => {
    members
      .filter((member: Tourist) => {
        return member.createdIn === touristCreatedIn && !member.isEmployee;
      })
      .forEach((member: any, index: any) => {
        personSchema
          .validate(member, { abortEarly: false })
          .then(() => {
            setFieldError({
              [index]: {}
            })
          })
          .catch((errs: any) => {
            setFieldError({})
            errs?.inner?.forEach((err: any) => {
              setFieldError((prev)=> ({
                ...prev,
                [index]: {
                  ...prev[index],
                  [err.path]: err.message,
                },
              }))
            });
          });

        personSchema
          .isValid(member)
          .then((v: any) => {
            console.log('тут', v, index)
            handleSelfValidation(v, index); // запуск хендлера 

          })
          .catch((err: any) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.error('TouristData YUP isValid Err', err);
          });
      });
    // setTimeout(handleInfoCheck);
  };

const handleInfoCheck = () => {
    setFirstVisit();

    if (
      Object.values(isFormsValid).every((item: any) => {
        return item === true;
      })
    ) {
      switch (permissionType) {
        case 'tour':
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tour-data`);
          break;
        case PERMISSION_TYPE_TRANZIT:
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tranzit-data`);
          break;
        default:
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tour-data`);
          break;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`setIsFormsValid` это асинхронная функция, в то время как `console.log()` это синхронный код. Соответсвенно `console.log()` выполняется раньше чем изменится состояние. Поэтому в консоли будет отображено старое состояние. Вот пример:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("very old");

  const buttonHandler = () => {
    setState("brand new");

    console.log(`state is`, state);
  };

  return <button onClick={buttonHandler}>Click me</button>;
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Для корректного отображения `state` после его изменения можно воспользоваться хуком `useEffect`, добавив в массив зависимостей необходимый `state` который нужно отслеживать:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("very old");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`state is `, state);
  }, [state]);

  const buttonHandler = () => {
    setState("brand new");
  };

  return <button onClick={buttonHandler}>Click me</button>;
};

// export default App;


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Понял, но как тут вопрос, что useEffect будет срабатывать всегда когда изменяется state который в зависимости, как мне сделать чтобы функция setTimeout(handleInfoCheck); которая закомментирована, работала с обновленным state, а не со старым?

Comment: Добавил ее в вопрос

Comment: А какая цель использования `setTimeout` ?